# What's the correct header to use when using API Key based authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, http-headers

I'm trying to create an API that uses API key based protection. The key is generated when a user is created, with a hook. Now I'm not sure what authorization schema to use with it. The avialable ones (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) don't seem correct. I have in my `applications_controller`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

  protected

  def authenticate
    authenticate_token || render_unauthorized
  end

  def authenticate_token
    authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
      @current_user = User.find_by_api_key(token)
    end
  end

  def render_unauthorized(realm = 'Application')
    self.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = %(Token realm='#{realm}')
    render json: 'Bad credentials', status: :unauthorized
  end
end
```

But I know that this is not correct:

`self.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = %(Token realm='#{realm}')`

There is no `Token` authorization schema. What should I use instead? I'm not finding much information about it.

I also know that Basic is not the correct type because it's not a `user:password` encoded in base64. Maybe `X-Api-Key`? I would like some help in the matter if possible :].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header of the form `Token token="####################"`, though you don't need to do this yourself. Use the code provided in [the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html):

```
authorization = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(users(:dhh).token)
get "/notes/1.xml", headers: { 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => authorization }
```

Comment: But where is the spec of this schema? I have not found it on https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml

Comment: There is no spec for this. HTTP only defines Basic and Digest. Then there's OAuth, is not in HTTP spec, but has a spec of its own. The Rails Token auth is just Rails. There are other APIs with token authentication, each of them slightly different.

Comment: I see. I'm also a bit confused about this `authorization = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(users(:dhh).token)`. Where should I put this code? And what is `dhh`? :thinking:

Comment: It is a literal example from Rails docs. `users(:dhh)` is presumably the `User` object representing David Heinemeier Hansson, the creator of Rails. You can use `...encode_credentials("####################")`, the method just adds stuff to make it conform to the expected syntax.